# detect pip in setup.py

Tags: python, pip, easy-install

Gist: What is the best way to detect in setup.py that we are being triggered by `pip install package`?

Background:
I have a package (bindings for a C-library), for which I provide eggs that include the library itself.  In my readme/docs I note that this package is 'easy_install-able' on certain platforms.  When building from source (e.g. with pip), the library itself is a build dependency.  The problem is that I somewhat regularly have confused users who mistakenly believe that pip is a full replacement for easy_install, and expect `pip install package` to work on systems without the library, or even without a compiler, where the egg is what they really want.

I would like to detect that the build has been triggered by pip, so I can provide a friendly "pip != easy_install" message if it fails due to lacking the library.  It doesn't need to be perfect, just catch the most common cases of `pip install package`. On inspection, it doesn't seem like there is a particularly robust way to do this, and the best I have come up with is:

```
probably_using_pip = '--single-version-externally-managed' in sys.argv
```

Is there a better (or better yet, official) way to detect pip from setup.py?

Comment: Why does the error message need to be any different than when running "setup.py install" when the library is not present?

Comment: When you run `setup.py install`, you are certainly building from source. When you run `pip install` people might be expecting binaries but not getting them (users really do not understand the differences between pip and easy_install). This question is no longer relevant to my particular case, because pip 1.5 supports wheels by default.

Comment: Some more context: at the time of asking (two years ago), my package was frequently installed on machines that have no compiler, and pip supported no binary formats. easy_install worked just fine, but pip would fail to compile. Because of this, I wanted to inform people whose `pip install` failed that easy_install might be preferable.

Answer (score 3):

`__file__` in setup gives something like `/tmp/pip-DNpsLw-build/setup.py` if ran from pip.

```
from setuptools import setup

def determineInstaller():
    if 'pip' in __file__:
        print('========pip triggered build========') #add smiley for friendliness :)
    return 'dummy description'

setup(name='bla',
      version='0.0',
      description=determineInstaller(),
      )
```

Comment: That's another pretty good note, though I would want to be more specific to reduce false positives, e.g.: `using_pip = os.path.basename(os.path.dirname(__file__)).startswith('pip-')`.  Given that nobody is providing an answer that is documented or official, and not vulnerable to false positives and/or changes in private APIs, it would seem that pip authors have no intention for packages to be able to tell that pip is in use.

Comment: `__file__` solution doesn't seem to be working with Py 2.7 2014-10-27, no 'pip' in `__file__`.  `os.environ` has a key '_' with value '/run/shm/r/ven/bin/pip' though.  This is installing via `pip install -e . -U`, so perhaps the `__file__` solution works with more typical pip installs, but maybe the `_` key is more general?

Answer (score -2):

Could you perhaps try using subprocess/os to try to run pip, then if it fails, you know there is no pip.

Comment: But if it doesn't, it won't mean anything.

Comment: Knowing that pip exists doesn't help, because I am looking for whether it's actually in use.  Plus, an easier check for pip's presence would be `import pip`.

Answer (score -2):

Have you considered building [wheels](http://pythonwheels.com) that pip can install?

Comment: I do build wheels now. When I asked this question, wheels didn't exist.